# Javascript canvas, how to use the rotate function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm making a simple game using canvas in Javascript. To boil it down I have a player and multiple targets that the player can shoot. But when firing a bullet, I can't seem to get the rotation down.

I made a new file to try out the rotation of a bullet to see if I could figure out what I was doing wrong in my original game project. But nonetheless couldn't.

This is the HTML file, the js is included in a script tag. Any help to help me figure out how the rotation works, as well as translate would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="game"></canvas>
  </body>

  <script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 500;

    let p1 = {
      x: 10,
      y: 40,
    };

    let p2 = {
      x: 300,
      y: 400,
    };

    let dx = p2.x - p1.x;
    let dy = p2.y - p1.y;
    let angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) + Math.PI / 2;

    let bulletX = p2.x;
    let bulletY = p2.y;

    console.log(angle, dx, dy);

    function loop() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
      ctx.fillRect(p1.x, p1.y, 10, 10);

      ctx.fillStyle = "green";
      ctx.fillRect(p2.x, p2.y, 10, 10);

      ctx.save();
      bulletX += 5 * Math.cos(angle);
      bulletY += 5 * Math.sin(angle);

      ctx.translate(bulletX, bulletY);
      ctx.rotate(angle);
      ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
      ctx.fillRect(bulletX - p2.x, bulletY - p2.y, 5, 15);
      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      ctx.restore();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the green square to shoot the bullet down?

Comment: @AnasSafi, the green square should shoot a bullet at the blue square. In the game I'm making the player position is static, and will always be below the targets.

Answer (score 2):

To make bullet travel from the green square to the blue square you should switch the positions of `p1` and `p2` in the angle calculation, because `p1` represents the player (blue square), and `p2` represents the target (green square).

This is full code:

```js
    const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 500;

    let p1 = {
      x: 10,
      y: 40,
    };

    let p2 = {
      x: 300,
      y: 400,
    };

    let dx = p1.x - p2.x;
    let dy = p1.y - p2.y;
    let angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

    let bulletX = p2.x;
    let bulletY = p2.y;

    function loop() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
      ctx.fillRect(p1.x, p1.y, 10, 10);

      ctx.fillStyle = "green";
      ctx.fillRect(p2.x, p2.y, 10, 10);

      bulletX += 5 * Math.cos(angle);
      bulletY += 5 * Math.sin(angle);

      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(bulletX, bulletY);
      ctx.rotate(angle);
      ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
      ctx.fillRect(-7.5, -2.5, 15, 5);
      ctx.restore();

      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="game"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```